# No encuentro el elemento Reporte

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

estoy teniendo un problema al querer agregar un nuevo reporte, ya que no me sale la opción cuando quiero agregar un nuevo elemento de reporte. Ya antes tenia instalado el Crystal, lo tuve que desintalar y volver a instalarlo, y ahora no me sale esta opción que les digo, realice la instalación correcta, no me surgieron errores al instalarlo, al Crystal lo descargue desde la pagina oficial.. Alguien sabe a que se debe y cual es la solución ?
Les dejo una imagen..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor si alguien sabe la solución me la hace saber ? Desde ya muchas gracias !

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Crystal estás utilizando? ¿Qué versión de VS?

Comment: @CarlosPozos la version de crystal es la 13.0.0 y la de visual es la 2012 professional. Cada vez que instalo el crystal, es como que si le faltaran unos elementos, ya que por eso no me muestra los reportes, sabes porque sera ? Saludos